# Angular run block with async call

Tags: angularjs

I try to to ask a service in a angular run block but it clearly appears that rest of the code is still executed BEFORE the service response.

```
.run(function(Service, $location){
    Service.whoami().$promise.then(function(data){
        $location.path("home");
    },function(){
        //DO SOMETHING
    });
})
```

By exemple, typing directly the url [...]/#/home when HomeController is

```
.controller("LoginCtrl",  [,
    function(){
        console.log("Login ctrl");
    }
])
```

I got the diplay "Login ctrl" in console... THEN the whoami callback is executed.

Is there a way to prevent that? I wanna block run block until I got response or error from whoami call.

Comment: You cannot prevent the controller from being instantiated before the whoami resolves. But, if you are using `ngRoute` you could use `$routeProvider`'s `resolve` property.